# Intellij Formatting variable declarations

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Does intellij have an option to align javascript variable declarations like so

```
var x     = "x",
    yyyy  = "y";
```

Note that the `=` are aligned neatly.  I can't find an option to do that....worse, if I do it by hand, and then format the file, I lose the alignment on the `=`.

Answer (score 11):

IDEA11 can definitely align javascript properties - see the Other tab on the Javascript code style.

In the Java code style options there is Wrapping and Braces - Field groups - Align in columns.

However, for js variables you might have to resort to a plugin.

Try DefinitionEqualizer.

Answer (score 1):

Editor > Code Style > Javascript > 'Other' tab

Formatting options:

- Align object properties: **On colon**
- Align 'var' statements and assignments: **Align multiline 'var' statements**